# Какой функцией в Swift обменять кортежи?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть 2 кортежа с одинаковыми типами данных, подскажите какой функцией обменять в них значения?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `swap`

```
var t1 = (1, 2, 3)
var t2 = (4, 5, 6)
swap(&t1, &t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

можно так же через tuple (a, b) = (b, a)